# How to add RectTransform function for Main Camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to bind the RectTransform function to the Main Camera, but the console throws error CS1002.
Perhaps I made a mistake in the Main Camera entry. Can you help?
Here is the part of the code that throws the error:

```
RectTransform recT = content.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
RectTransform recT = Main Camera.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
recT.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
_group = GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>();
setAchievs();
```

I tried to write Main Camera not only through a space, but also through an underscore and together, but it didn’t help

Comment: `Main Camera.GetComponent` isn't valid `c#` ... do you mean [`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the code line number 3 i,e CS1002 which represents that you have forgot to put semicolon. Because you have missed a **Space** in the Line that says `Main Camera` it should have been `MainCamera` if you have referenced it. Otherwise it should be

`Camera.main.GetComponent<RectTransform>();`
to get the MainCamera's RectTransform.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now it throws an error with the following content: MissingComponentException: There is no 'RectTransform' attached to the "Main Camera" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a RectTransform to the game object "Main Camera". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. achmenu.Start ()

Comment: Because your camera may not have a RectTransform instead it will just have a transform just add RectTransform Component to it in inspector it will fix it

Comment: Everything worked. Thank you very much!